# How can method change array, and get changes mapped to original array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on an $arr and frequently need to check if an index is "initialized" before I use it.

These indexes differ in the level of nesting

```
$arr[$ia]
$arr[$ia][$ib][$ic]
```

but when I initialize them, it's always the same way

```
$arr[$ia]           = array('name'=>array(), 'components'=>array());
$arr[$ia][$ib][$ic] = array('name'=>array(), 'components'=>array());
```

I do it exactly like this

```
//if $arr[$ia] is not set, set it, then use it
if(!isset($arr[$ia])){
   $arr[$ia] = array('name'=>array(), 'components'=>array());
}
$arr[$ia]['name'] = 'some value';

or

//if $arr[$ia][$ib] is not set, set it, then use it
if(!isset($arr[$ia][$ib])){
   $arr[$ia][$ib] = array('name'=>array(), 'components'=>array());
}
$arr[$ia][$ib]['name'] = 'some other value';
```

I want to move the initialization step into a method so I don't have the `array('name'=>array(), 'components'=>array())` code all over the place like this. How do I do this so that the original array always gets updated, and given that the level of nesting changes?

**It seems that passing the array as &$arr is not allowed in php 5.3. I get this error. `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated`.**

Comment: Why not have a function? $arr[$ia][$ib] = my_function(); ?

Comment: @jValdron But what is the function going to return? I mean what's the best way to make sure the original array gets updated?

Comment: Your function could return the initialization: `array('name'=>array(), 'components'=>array());`, I probably just don't understand correctly the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initArray(&$ar,$i) {
  if (!isset($ar[$i])) $ar[$i]=array('name'=>array(), 'components'=>array());
}
```

and

```
initArray(&$arr,$ia);
$arr[$ia]['name'] = 'some value';
```

resp.

```
ínitArray(&$arr[$ia],$ib);
$arr[$ia][$ib]['name'] = 'some other value';
```

If you allways assign the name, you can pimp this up to

```
function initArrayName(&$ar, $i, $name) {
  initArray(&$ar,$i);
  $arr[$i]['name']=$name;
}
```

and

```
initArrayName(&$arr,$ia,'some value');
```

resp.

```
ínitArrayName(&$arr[$ia],$ib,'some other value');
```

Comment: +1 but I'm getting `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated`. I'm working with php 5.3. Looks like they made changes so this isn't allowed anymore.